# Find Chr(13) in a text and split them in C#

Tags: c#

I have written two lines of code below in vb6. The code is :

```
d = InStr(s, data1, Chr(13), 1) ' Fine 13 keycode(Enter) form a text data.

sSplit2 = Split(g, Chr(32))     ' Split with 13 Keycode(Enter)
```

But I can't write above code in C#. Please help me out. How can I write the above code in C#.

Comment: Typo? You mention Chr(13) (CR) but write Chr(32) (SPACE). Or are you looking to split strings on space at the first carriage return? Please update your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [string.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx):

```
string str = "Test string" + (char)13 + "some other string";
string[] splitted = str.Split((char)13);
```

Or you can use:

```
string[] splitted = str.Split('\r');
```

For the above you will get two strings in your `splitted` array.

Answer (score 2):

the equivalnt code for `sSplit2 = Split(g, Chr(32))` is

```
string[] sSplit2 = g.Split('\n');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int index = sourceStr.IndexOf((char)13);
String[] splittArr = sourceStr.Split((char)13);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        const char CarriageReturn = (char)13;
        string testString = "This is a test " + CarriageReturn + " string.";
        //find first occurence of CarriageReturn
        int index = testString.IndexOf(CarriageReturn);
        //split according to CarriageReturn
        string[] split = testString.Split(CarriageReturn);
```

If you want to encapsulate the carriage return depending on whether you are running in a unix or non unix environment you can use Environment.NewLine . See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.100).aspx .

```
        string testString2 = "This is a test " + Environment.NewLine + " string.";
        //find first occurence of Environment.NewLine
        int index2 = testString2.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine);
        //split according to Environment.NewLine
        string[] split2 = testString2.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```